# PHP variable in javascript "Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I'm having a problem trying to use a `PHP` `variable` within `JavaScript`. I keep getting the following message.

"Invalid or unexpected token. Message:  Undefined variable: example."

I'm unsure why example is being undefined, as it is defined within the php code. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $example = '2';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_var = "<?php echo json_encode($example); ?>";
</script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have also tried the following `javascript` that results in the same problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_var = "<?php echo $example; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: you missed semi colon after `$example = '2'` that might be problem.

Comment: @SoniyaReddy I think you missed what he is trying to do. `$example` should be output as `var php_var = "2";`

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized I had read (skimmed) too fast.

Comment: `json_encode` will add double quotes, making `var php_var = ""2"";` Having said that `var php_var = "<?php echo $example; ?>";` worked as expected for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your original code has a syntax error: `$example = '2'` needs a semicolon.
Secondly, the next piece of code is just assigning the string `<?php echo $example; ?>` to the *JavaScript* variable *php_var* where the `$example` *PHP* variable is first substituted. The `$example` variable should be initiated properly first, however, for this to work.

As a separate note: JS cannot execute PHP directly -- only a PHP **server** can do so. What you're most likely trying to do is this:

```
<?php
    $example = '2';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_var = '<?php echo $example ;?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I added this in my footer.php and it worked. For some strange reason, $example when created on my body page is not going to the footer.

Comment: I'm confused as to what is different in your answer and the question? I cannot see any difference except `'` being changed to `"`. But I doubt that is the actual solution... Both single and double quotes don't work for me. Why could that be? UPDATE: they actually do print the php var, but because of the error, the rest of the javascript is broken.

Comment: this is assigning php_var  to a literal string.  This didn't work for me. i am using chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, use single quotes

```
<?php
  $example = '2';
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var php_var = '<?php echo  $example; ?>';
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried and working both variant:

```
<?php
    $example = '2';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($example); ?>;
    console.log(php_var);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_va = "<?php echo $example; ?>";
    console.log(php_va);
</script>
```